# Referência a objetos

Tags: java, android, referência

Até que ponto uma referência para um objeto é exatamente igual a ele?

Vou explicar minha situação:

Dentro de um *adapter*, eu preciso imprimir um determinado item em uma lista. O critério para colorir esse item está num objeto que está fora do meu *adapter*.

Esse objeto é um mapa com o relacionamento entre usuários e canais numa rede de IRC. E o critério é o nível do usuário no canal.

Se eu tivesse uma instância da classe do canal dentro do *adapter*, me ajudaria muito, mas como saber se essa instancia vai refletir exatamente o estado do canal dentro do cliente IRC?

O canal é obtido da seguinte maneira:

```
    // objeto que mapeia usuarios-canais
    UserChannelDao dao = ircClient.getUserChannelDao();

    // objeto que representa o canal 
    Channel canal = dao.getChannel("#canal");
```

É seguro manter um objeto do canal dentro do *adapter*?

Comment: *Normalmente* [i.e. do ponto de vista da linguagem] ter uma, duas, várias referências para o mesmo objeto significa simplesmente que só há **um** objeto - as referências são simplesmente cópias do **endereço em memória** desse objeto. Ou seja, se você mexer no objeto, ele ficará mexido, e seja qual for a referência que você use para consultá-lo ela encontrará esse objeto no seu estado atualizado. Não vou postar isso como resposta, entretanto, pois desconheço a situação *específica* dos objetos mencionados (pois uma coisa é a linguagem, outra é a estruturação da plataforma Android).

Comment: @mgibsonbr +1. Eu não sei que API que você está usando para interagir com IRC, mas acredito que você precisará atualizar sua lista quando um usuario entrar ou sair por exemplo. Verifique na sua API se ela não deixa você registrar listeners para eventos, por exemplo "OnUserLeftChannelListerner". Você implementa ela no seu adapter e quando de fato algo acontecer, você atualiza sua lista.

Comment: Se a referência fosse igual ao objeto, não seria uma referência ;)

Comment: Entendi. Então eu vou armazenar o objeto do Canal dentro do adapter.